# How to ______ a product to the group

Tags: verbs, business-language

I want to describe a process for 'welcoming a new product to the group'. I'm not particularly fond of the word 'welcoming' in this context. Onboarding doesn't seem to be a valid word either. Commissioning is a less favorable option. 
I can't seem to find any verb that accurately describes what I want to convey.
Any suggestions?

Comment: If “to the group” means “to our existing group/line of products,” you could perhaps consider using “enthusiastically” to modify a variety of less-than-welcoming verbs/phrases to help capture the feeling of “welcoming”:e.g., …. “We’re enthusiastically making room for [enthusiastically integrating/incorporating] this new product in [into] our [already outstanding] group/line of products.” If “the group” means “a group of people/investors/etc” then maybe you could use “enthusiastically” with any of the good answers given so far.

Comment: @PapaPoule Incorporate is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a million.

Answer (score 1):

Try [introduce](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/introduce), [announce](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/announce), or some synonym thereof.

Comment: 'Introduce' is closer but still not quite there.

Answer (score 1):

Try present, greet or embrace.

Comment: Sorry won't work in this context